# Empty metadata in RpcException from C# gRPC-server

Tags: c#, grpc

I cannot get metadata from an exception from an ASP.NET gRPC-server.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/grpc and add catching exceptions on GrpcGreeterClient.

server:

```cs
var metadata = new Metadata
            {
                { "user", "sd" }
            };
            throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.PermissionDenied, "Permission denied"), metadata);
```

client:

```cs
catch (RpcException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.PermissionDenied)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Trailers.Count);
                var userEntry = ex.Trailers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key == "user");
                Console.WriteLine($"User '{userEntry.Value}' does not have permission to view this portfolio.");
            }
```

I expect see ex.Trailers.Count to be 1 and "user" as key.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in Grpc.Net.Client 2.23.0, with 2.24.0 everything is OK.

Comment: For some reasons, it doesn’t work for me.